# If $T$ has a cyclic vector, prove that its restriction to an invariant subset also has a cyclic vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: V \to V$ be a linear transformation on the final dimensional vectorspace $V$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$. Let $W$ be a nonzero proper $T$-invariant subspace of $V$. Suppose that the characteristic polynomial $f_T$ of $T$ satisfies $f_T(0)=0$. Show that if $T$ has a cyclic vector, then $T|_W:W \to W$ has a cyclic vector.

**My attempt**

Suppose $W=\rm{span} \{\alpha_1,\ldots \ \alpha_k\}$, where $k < n=\dim \ V$.
Extend this basis to get a basis $\mathcal{B} = \{\alpha_1,\ldots \ \alpha_n\}$ for $V$.

Some observations :
Since $T$ has a cyclic vector, its minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial are the same: $f_T=p_T$. Since $W$ is $T$-invariant, it minimal polynomial $p_{T,W}$ divides $p_T$ and its characteristic polynomial $f_{T,W}$ divides $f_T=p_T$. I need to show that $p_{T,W} = f_{T,W}$ which implies that $T|_W$ has a cyclic vector.

On the other hand $p_{T,W}$ divides $f_{T,W}$ by Cayley-Hamilton theorem. For sake of getting a contradiction, Assume that $\deg \ p_{T,W} < \deg \ f_{T,W}$. We know that there exists a polynomial $q$ of degree at least $1$ (since $W$ is proper) such that $(f_{T,W})(q)=p_T$. Now consider the product 
$$
(p_{T,W})(q)\neq p_T.\qquad\qquad\qquad(*)
$$
If I knew that $q(T)$ annihilates $\rm{span} \{\alpha_{k+1},\ldots \ \alpha_k\}$, then $(*)$ is a contracdiction. But so far I am not convinced about this.

So far I have not used the fact that $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$, i.e. if $v\neq0$ then $Tv \neq 0$, so I tried to use it!

Since $T$ has a cyclic vector $\alpha$, then $\{\alpha, T\alpha, \ldots ,T^{n-1}\alpha \}$ is a basis for $V$. Now suppose 
$$
c_1T\alpha+c_2T^2\alpha+ \ldots +c_nT^n\alpha=0.\qquad\qquad\qquad(**)
$$ 
I will show that all $c_i=0$, $(**)$ implies $$T(c_1\alpha+c_2T\alpha+ \ldots +c_nT^{n-1}\alpha)=0$$ which means that $$c_1\alpha+c_2T\alpha+ \ldots +c_nT^{n-1}\alpha=0$$ and hence $$c_1=c_2=\ldots=c_n=0$$ therefore $T\alpha$ is also a cyclic vector. Similarly we can show that $T^j\alpha$ is a cyclic vector for all $j\in \mathbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$! This implies that $T^j\alpha \notin W$ for all $j\in \mathbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$ because if $T^j\alpha \in W$ for some $j$, then $W$ and not be a proper subspace of $V$. I do not know if I am getting anywhere.

I would be very thankful to see any helpful comments/answers, Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by $f_T(0)=0$?

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathbb{F}$ is algebraically closed, then $T$ has a cyclic vector iff $p_T=f_T$ iff $T$ is nonderogatory iff $T$ admits only a finite number of invariant subspaces. Here $T|_W$ admits a finite number of invariant subspaces and then has a cyclic vector.

Comment: Thanks, but $\mathbb{F}$ is not necessarily algebraically closed ...

Answer (score 1):

If you view $V$ as $K[X]$ module where the module action is $f(X)v= f(T)v$, then any sub module is the $T$ invariant subspace. Now  $T$ has a cyclic vector iff $V$ is cyclic $K[X]$ module. And any sub module of a cyclic module over a PID is again cyclic..